# как передвинуть окно Matplotlib в Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Как на экране передвинуть окно графика, который вызываю в Matplotlib Python? Необходимо задать координаты окна графика на экране.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=plt.plot()
a=plt.show()
```

Comment: поискать вы поленились? https://www.programmersought.com/article/45311583006/

Comment: а зачем вы присваиваете результаты методов plot и show переменной `a`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449585/how-do-you-set-the-absolute-position-of-figure-windows-with-matplotlib